# How change shortcut for plugins in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying remap the shortcut for run easymotion in vim for the same key than I use in Emacs: shift + Enter

```
 nnoremap <S-Enter> :call easymotion-prefix() <CR>
```

running this vim show a warning alert than I'm missing some parenthesis, I try (easymotion-prefix) too..but this doesn't works neither

I wrote it inside my .vimrc, I don't know if I can do this or I need write directly inside the plugin, do I need remove the previous keymap? or change the original file [easymotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) , thanks!.....

Comment: easymotion-prefix isn't a function. All user defined functions start with a capital letter. (Also read the README the answer is in the Important Notes...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some digging, and this worked

```
map <S-Enter> <Plug>(easymotion-prefix)
```

Places to find this:

## `README.md`

The easiest way to find it may have been to visit the [plugin's Github page](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion), as here we can enjoy the browser's parsing of the markdown and source. That page opens to the bundle's `README.md`, which you can also read in your `~/.vim/bundle/vim-easymotion/` directory from the comfort of Vim.

## `:help`

Other sensible places to solve your problem, would have been the `:help easymotion.txt`, or if you don't have help files for your plugins properly aligned, you can simply visit `vim-easymotion/easymotion.txt`. You can bounce around in there as some other sections will point you closer, but `easymotion-custom-mappings` is the relevant section.

## `plugin/`

And if all else fails, you can check out the `plugin` directory, in this case we can inspect the `vim-easymotion/EasyMotion.vim` file. There, we can find a section,

```
" == Default key mapping {{{
if g:EasyMotion_do_mapping == 1
    " Prepare Prefix: {{{
    if exists('g:EasyMotion_leader_key')
        exec 'map ' . g:EasyMotion_leader_key . ' <Plug>(easymotion-prefix)'
    else
        if !hasmapto('<Plug>(easymotion-prefix)')
            map <Leader><Leader> <Plug>(easymotion-prefix)
        endif
    endif
    "}}}
```

where you can see it will only use the default if `!hasmapto('<Plug>(easymotion-prefix)')`, which is why

```
    map <S-Enter> <Plug>(easymotion-prefix)
```

fixes your problem.

I'm curious why

```
let g:EasyMotion_leader_key <S-Enter>
```

doesn't also work

## In general

In general, it may be easier to do a word search in the help file or plugin file for `<Plug>` or `<Leader><Leader>`.

Another candidate is `maplocalleader`. `vim-orgmode` frustrated me with overwriting my use of leader key, so I have `let maplocalleader='\'` to alleviate what may be common to other plugins as well.

Comment: Vim has great documentation i.e. `:h`. Most good plugins do as well. This includes EasyMotion. See `:h easymotion-leader-key` the answer to this exact question. See `:h easymotion` as well